# How to make underlying character legible when under a cursor in neovim

Tags: neovim, color-scheme

Very new to neovim so bear with me. I'm trying to figure our how to view a character easily when highlighted under a cursor in normal view. If you look at the screenshot, you'll know what I mean:
[image]

As one can see, that 'k' is barely legible. I followed Primeagen's 0 to lsp video and he has it like this
[image]

I'm not saying I want it like that but atleast it's possible! Any help would be appreciated. I've tried playing around with the highlight_group settings in rose-pine but it just changes the cursor color and doesn't do anything about the character color. I've resorted to changing from block to hor for now but would love to have block as its way clearer to see it.

Environment wise, I'm on windows using windows terminal (wsl2) with latest version of nvim

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's related to windows terminal as mentioned in this open issue
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15766